# Different cURL behaviour on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: php, curl

I'm using cURL to make some requests to external API. Everything works fine, I get some token with first request to use it later on to do stuff which require authorization header.

I add http header with function:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);`

And here's the problem. On Ubuntu environment I get correct response. On Windows - request time out (which probably is their API setting to not send response on wrong data). On both environment I have same headers, but different results.

Is there some environment specific settings that could make Windows request incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting value for  `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`. Set it to `0` to wait indefinitely to connect to the server, or any other value in seconds.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30) //wait for 30 sec.
```

Try this, maybe this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for a tip but already tried that. I tried increasing the value and setting it to 0 with no luck.